# Hibernate 4.2 Provider error

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

i try to upgrade my application from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4. 
the server is Jonas 5.2.2 that i can't upgrade.

I imported all required classes in the build path. 
when i deploy the application i have this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    ... 41 more
```

this is my persitence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="dataSource" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>superng</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you upgrade all Hibernate jars to the same version?  That referenced class (`InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider`) is not even part of Hibernate anymore.  So whatever is supplying that value is incorrect.  Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: problem is solved, it was jonas server tht override my import. i solved it by exclude all class in the classloader-filter.xml in jonas base directy